# Json VBA Parse - Run time error 424 - Object required

Tags: json, vba

I am trying to extract value for `regularMarketPreviousClose` from the Yahoo API json reponse.

I get a Run time error 424 - Object required, in the line - `Set price = reply("result")`.

Can someone figure out what's wrong in this code. I have provided both my code and the json data I get from Yahoo API.

Here is the json response text I get from yahoo API

```json
{
  "quoteResponse": {
    "result": [
      {
        "language": "en-US",
        "region": "US",
        "quoteType": "EQUITY",
        "typeDisp": "Equity",
        "quoteSourceName": "Delayed Quote",
        "triggerable": false,
        "customPriceAlertConfidence": "LOW",
        "currency": "USD",
        "tradeable": false,
        "exchange": "PNK",
        "shortName": "Tandy Leather Factory, Inc.",
        "longName": "Tandy Leather Factory, Inc.",
        "messageBoardId": "finmb_30741",
        "exchangeTimezoneName": "America/New_York",
        "exchangeTimezoneShortName": "EDT",
        "gmtOffSetMilliseconds": -14400000,
        "market": "us_market",
        "esgPopulated": false,
        "marketState": "REGULAR",
        "fullExchangeName": "Other OTC",
        "financialCurrency": "USD",
        "regularMarketOpen": 4.95,
        "averageDailyVolume3Month": 9237,
        "averageDailyVolume10Day": 22020,
        "fiftyTwoWeekLowChange": 1.2399998,
        "fiftyTwoWeekLowChangePercent": 0.33423173,
        "fiftyTwoWeekRange": "3.71 - 5.3",
        "fiftyTwoWeekHighChange": -0.35000038,
        "fiftyTwoWeekHighChangePercent": -0.066037804,
        "fiftyTwoWeekLow": 3.71,
        "fiftyTwoWeekHigh": 5.3,
        "dividendDate": 1407456000,
        "earningsTimestamp": 1639991127,
        "earningsTimestampStart": 1648065600,
        "earningsTimestampEnd": 1648238400,
        "trailingAnnualDividendRate": 0,
        "trailingPE": 50.510204,
        "trailingAnnualDividendYield": 0,
        "epsTrailingTwelveMonths": 0.098,
        "epsForward": 0.43,
        "epsCurrentYear": 0.26,
        "priceEpsCurrentYear": 19.038462,
        "sharesOutstanding": 8543230,
        "bookValue": 6.038,
        "fiftyDayAverage": 4.9554,
        "fiftyDayAverageChange": -0.005400181,
        "fiftyDayAverageChangePercent": -0.0010897568,
        "twoHundredDayAverage": 4.89935,
        "twoHundredDayAverageChange": 0.050649643,
        "twoHundredDayAverageChangePercent": 0.010338033,
        "marketCap": 42288988,
        "forwardPE": 11.511627,
        "priceToBook": 0.8198078,
        "sourceInterval": 15,
        "exchangeDataDelayedBy": 0,
        "averageAnalystRating": "2.0 - Buy",
        "firstTradeDateMilliseconds": 749136600000,
        "priceHint": 4,
        "regularMarketChange": -0.05000019,
        "regularMarketChangePercent": -1.0000038,
        "regularMarketTime": 1648141256,
        "regularMarketPrice": 4.95,
        "regularMarketDayHigh": 4.95,
        "regularMarketDayRange": "4.95 - 4.95",
        "regularMarketDayLow": 4.95,
        "regularMarketVolume": 604,
        "regularMarketPreviousClose": 5,
        "displayName": "Tandy Leather Factory",
        "symbol": "TLFA"
      },
      {
        "language": "en-US",
        "region": "US",
        "quoteType": "EQUITY",
        "typeDisp": "Equity",
        "quoteSourceName": "Nasdaq Real Time Price",
        "triggerable": true,
        "customPriceAlertConfidence": "HIGH",
        "currency": "USD",
        "tradeable": false,
        "exchange": "NCM",
        "shortName": "ChromaDex Corporation",
        "longName": "ChromaDex Corporation",
        "messageBoardId": "finmb_5034211",
        "exchangeTimezoneName": "America/New_York",
        "exchangeTimezoneShortName": "EDT",
        "gmtOffSetMilliseconds": -14400000,
        "market": "us_market",
        "esgPopulated": false,
        "marketState": "REGULAR",
        "fullExchangeName": "NasdaqCM",
        "financialCurrency": "USD",
        "regularMarketOpen": 2.52,
        "averageDailyVolume3Month": 421352,
        "averageDailyVolume10Day": 520790,
        "fiftyTwoWeekLowChange": 0.5400001,
        "fiftyTwoWeekLowChangePercent": 0.2797928,
        "fiftyTwoWeekRange": "1.93 - 11.2",
        "fiftyTwoWeekHighChange": -8.73,
        "fiftyTwoWeekHighChangePercent": -0.77946424,
        "fiftyTwoWeekLow": 1.93,
        "fiftyTwoWeekHigh": 11.2,
        "earningsTimestamp": 1646841720,
        "earningsTimestampStart": 1651694400,
        "earningsTimestampEnd": 1652126400,
        "trailingAnnualDividendRate": 0,
        "trailingAnnualDividendYield": 0,
        "epsTrailingTwelveMonths": -0.404,
        "epsForward": -0.15,
        "epsCurrentYear": -0.29,
        "priceEpsCurrentYear": -8.5172415,
        "sharesOutstanding": 68126000,
        "bookValue": 0.464,
        "fiftyDayAverage": 2.664,
        "fiftyDayAverageChange": -0.194,
        "fiftyDayAverageChangePercent": -0.072822824,
        "twoHundredDayAverage": 5.90605,
        "twoHundredDayAverageChange": -3.4360502,
        "twoHundredDayAverageChangePercent": -0.5817848,
        "marketCap": 168724224,
        "forwardPE": -16.466665,
        "priceToBook": 5.323276,
        "sourceInterval": 15,
        "exchangeDataDelayedBy": 0,
        "pageViewGrowthWeekly": 0.02642558,
        "averageAnalystRating": "1.7 - Buy",
        "firstTradeDateMilliseconds": 1214400600000,
        "priceHint": 4,
        "regularMarketChange": -0.03999996,
        "regularMarketChangePercent": -1.5936241,
        "regularMarketTime": 1648145420,
        "regularMarketPrice": 2.47,
        "regularMarketDayHigh": 2.99,
        "regularMarketDayRange": "2.45 - 2.99",
        "regularMarketDayLow": 2.45,
        "regularMarketVolume": 221155,
        "regularMarketPreviousClose": 2.51,
        "bid": 2.46,
        "ask": 2.47,
        "bidSize": 9,
        "askSize": 10,
        "displayName": "ChromaDex",
        "symbol": "CDXC"
      }
    ],
    "error": null
  }
}
```

Here is my VBA code

```vb
Sub RequestURL()
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim rstring As String
    Dim item As Object
    Dim lrow As Integer: lrow = Range("A10000").End(xlUp).Row
    rstring = "https://yfapi.net/v6/finance/quote?region=US&lang=en&symbols="
    
    For i = 2 To lrow
        rstring = rstring & Tsheet.Range("A" & i).Value & "%2C"
    Next i

    rstring = Left(rstring, Len(rstring) - 3)

    Dim request As New WinHttpRequest
    Dim key As String
    key = "mykey"

    request.Open "get", rstring
    request.SetRequestHeader "X-API-Key", key
    request.Send

    If request.Status <> 200 Then
        MsgBox request.ResponseText
    Else
        MsgBox request.ResponseText
    End If
 
    ' To access Data
 
    Dim reply As Object
    Set reply = JsonConverter.ParseJson(request.ResponseText)

    Dim price As Collection
    Set price = reply("result")

    Dim result As Dictionary
    For Each result In price
        Debug.Print result("regularMarketPreviousClose")
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: You are ignoring `quoteResponse` the level above?

Comment: `Set price = reply("quoteResponse")("result")`

Comment: Thanks a ton GSerg & Tim Williams. This works.

Answer (score 0):

JSON uses name value pairs format.
Curly brackets hold objects and square ones hold array.
Result is an object itself and holds array of objects in it.
Since , it is inside quoteResponse. You must address it first and then the result inside it.

```
Set price = reply("quoteResponse")("result")
```